# Why is promise.finally in my Vue project not working in Edge?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, polyfills

I'm having tremendous trouble getting my polyfills to work in Edge. I've tried to follow the documentation with various attempts all not working. It seems to be promise.finally specifically that isn't working. This happens in a **vuex module** so I tried adding vuex to transpileDependencies in vue.config but with no luck.

[image]

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset', {
    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
  }]],
};
```

In my main.js I have the following two imports in the very top:

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

My vue.config.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const webpack = require('webpack');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // Set up all the aliases we use in our app.
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 6,
      }),
    ],
  },
  css: {
    // Enable CSS source maps.
    sourceMap: !isProd,
  },
  transpileDependencies: ['vuex'],
};
```

Note as mentioned above I have tried both with and without the transpileDepedencies. It says here [vue/babel-preset-app](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app) that `es7.promise.finally` is included as a default polyfill

Versions:

- Microsoft Edge: 44.18
- Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
- @vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2"
- "core-js": "^3.6.4"
- "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3"

**Update 13/02**

So I tried to type Promise.prototype on my site in edge and it does appear it is polyfilled: [image: here]

So currently I'm investigating if some part of my chain (axios/vue axios) does not return a promise. Since it is working in chrome I'm suspecting that a part of the chain is not being polyfilled correctly?

This is my entire chain:

```
/* VUEX MODULE ACTION */  
[a.ALL_CUSTOMERS](context) {
    context.commit(m.SET_CUSTOMER_LOADING, true);
    CustomerService.getAll()
      .then(({ data }) => {
        context.commit(m.SET_CUSTOMERS, data);
      })
      .finally(() => context.commit(m.SET_CUSTOMER_LOADING, false));
  },

/* CUSTOMER SERVICE */
import ApiService from '@/common/api.service';
const CustomerService = {
  getAll() {
    const resource = 'customers/';
    return ApiService.get(resource);
  },
...
}

/* API SERVICE */
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

const ApiService = {
  init() {
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
    let baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_APIURL;
    Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl;
  },

  setHeader() {
    Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${getToken()}`;
  },

  get(resource) {
    this.setHeader();
    return Vue.axios.get(`${resource}`);
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Edge shouldn't need a polyfill because it supports `finally()` on Promise since v18

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the EdgeHTML version? You can find it right below where you find the Edge version. I ask because CanIUse bases support off of that. From their site: `*Version number used for Edge is based on the number of EdgeHTML rather than Edge itself. This is because EdgeHTML is the engine for Edge that is related to feature support change.`

Comment: Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362

Comment: Edge should tell you that it's a promise. It rather says that it's an object. So the returned object isn't the expected promise.

Comment: It's just a regular  axios call, do you have any suggestions what I can look into?

Comment: Microsoft Edge: 44.18 - you seem to be using a bit of an outdated version of this browser. according to this website: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/edge

Are you developing for Xbox ONE or windows Phone?

Comment: @dev-cyprium this version is reasonably new (may 19, 2019). Their versioning jumps a bit. I'm just developing for a regular browser

Comment: This question could be improved by providing a boiled down repo reproducing the issue so other people can help. A site like https://codesandbox.io/ could be used for this.

Comment: It seems that compat tables are wrong. https://caniuse.com/#feat=promise-finally tells that Edge supports it since 18, but I have 41 and I get `undefined` from `(new Promise(()=>{})).finally` in the console. (Every other modern browser gives function.)
So couldn't it be Babel simply omits that polyfill because it thinks it is not needed, according compat tables?

Comment: NM, my "Edge 41" actually has EdgeHTML 16 what is that number Caniuse displays so it really doesn't support `finally`. Anyway, your "Edge 44" should have "EdgeHTML 18" like you wrote, so `Promise.prototype.finally` should be present even without polyfills, according caniuse. Is it correct? (Then it really seems there is non-promise object passed in your chain somewhere…)

Comment: To check: is this question even still valid? Are you loading a shim for a version of Edge that supports .finally and that broke it, or are you trying to use finally in a version of Edge that _doesn't_ support it and the polyfill you've selected is simply misbehaving?

Comment: I'm not loading any custom polyfills or shims - simply using the babel default polyfills as listed. So some of the default polyfill is misbehaving I think

Comment: @dev-cyprium The 80.xxxx version refers to Chromium based HTML engine, version 18.18362 is pretty much up to date in Edges using Microsoft Edge HTML.

Comment: why should it? isn't Edge a tool to donwload Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I have ever faced that issue before.
Only finally didn't work on Edge.
I updated finally like below VVV and it worked.

This should handle the propagation of the thenable's [species](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) in addition to the behaviors detailed below:

```
Promise.prototype.finally = Promise.prototype.finally || {
  finally (fn) {
    const onFinally = value => Promise.resolve(fn()).then(() => value);
    return this.then(
      result => onFinally(result),
      reason => onFinally(Promise.reject(reason))
    );
  }
}.finally;
```

This implementation is based on the documented behavior of [finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) and depends on [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) being compliant to the specification:

> A finally callback will not receive any argument, since there's no
>   reliable means of determining if the promise was fulfilled or
>   rejected. This use case is for precisely when you do not care about
>   the rejection reason, or the fulfillment value, and so there's no need
>   to provide it.
>
> Unlike `Promise.resolve(2).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be
>   resolved with undefined), `Promise.resolve(2).finally(() => {})` will be
>   resolved with 2.
>
> Similarly, unlike `Promise.reject(3).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which
>   will be fulfilled with undefined), `Promise.reject(3).finally(() => {})`
>   will be rejected with 3.
>
> **Note**: A throw (or returning a rejected promise) in the finally
>   callback will reject the new promise with the rejection reason
>   specified when calling throw().

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/579).

In theory, Edge provides a Promise polyfill for finally, but perhaps something is going on with the feature detection or your browserlist and you need to provide a polyfill :shrug:

I would delete both the Vue babel plugin and core-js from your project and then npm install them fresh.

- `npm install @vue/cli-plugin-babel --save-dev`
- `npm install core-js --save`

Also, make sure you're using core-js@3 via your config (babel.config.js) [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md)

Lastly, there's a few Github issues talking about polyfills + Promises with regards to the other 3rd party libraries executed in your vuex store. Add all three of those libraries (axios, vue-axios, vuex) to your `transpileDependencies` section. If that fixes it, start removing the dependencies to see if they're needed.

Comment: Tried all your suggestions unfortunately the same outcome :(

Comment: Weird. Is a third party plugin deleting Promise.finally?

Comment: sorry for late answer. How can I tell if a third party plugin deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.browserslistrc` file to your projects root with the following content:

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
```

See https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#best-practices information on `last versions` configuration.

---

If this does not resolve missing poly-fill, try disabling the plugin you are using that limits the number of chunks in order to ensure that this is not causing any poly-fills to be omitted.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
    maxChunks: 6,
  }),
],
```

Comment: I already have the browserslistrc with the versions you've listed. Just tested  without the plugin - had no effect :(

Comment: My babel plugin file only has:

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}

Comment: and your promise.finally works in edge? Any possibility you can share your package list and configurations so I can try to deduct which package causes the problem?

Comment: I always create my projects using https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create but Edge 18+ supports finally() there is no need for a poly-fill, only for Internet Explorer?

Comment: Your issue might be sprouting from that ApiService you are using it might not be returning a native Promise but an emulated one of its own creation.
Try setting up same call using axios directly as a test.